# Interactive Brokers TWS: How to handle daily restart in python?

Tags: python, interactive-brokers, tws

I've built an IB TWS application in python. All seems to work fine, but I'm struggling with one last element.

TWS requires a daily logout or restart. I've opted for the daily restart at a set time so I could easily anticipate a restart of my application at certain times (at least, so I thought.)

My program has one class, called `InteractiveBrokersAPI` which subclasses the ECClient and EWrapper. Upon the start of my program, I create this instance and it successfully connects to and works with TWS. Now, say that TWS restarts daily at 23:00. I have implemented logic in my program that creates a new instance of my `InteractiveBrokersAPI`, and calls `run()` on it af 23:15. This too seems to work. I know this because upon creation, `InteractiveBrokersAPI` calls `reqAccountUpdates()` and I can see these updates coming in after my restart. When I try to actually commit a trade the next day, I get an error that it's not connected.

Does anyone else have experience in how to handle this? I am wondering how others have fixed this issue. Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this doesnt exactly answer your question, but have you looked at ib_insync